# what is the camera filter used to correct daylight balanced sources to tungsten-balanced film?

Tags: filters, color-correction

- what is the camera filter used to correct tungsten light sources for daylight balanced film?
- what is the camera filter used to correct daylight balanced sources to tungsten-balanced film?

Answer (score 3):

- 80 filter corrects tungsten light sources to daylight balanced film
- 85 filter corrects daylight sources to tungsten-balanced film

There are variations - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wratten_number